# Is it possible to have a non-public parameterless constructor that can be used for model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have a following POCO class. I don not want the parameterless constructor to be public.

```
public class FileDownloadRequest
    {
       //public FileDownloadRequest() { }
        public FileDownloadRequest(int fileId, RepositoryFolderTypes fileType) //RepositoryFolderTypes is an enum, not a class
        {
            this.FileId = fileId;
            this.FileType = fileType;
        }
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public RepositoryFolderTypes FileType { get; set; } //an enum
    }
```

When I am trying a `https://10.27.8.6/Files/DownloadFile?fileId=1&folderType=SRC` request to the following controller action, I get an error saying that no parameterless constructor exists for this object.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile([FromUri] FileDownloadRequest request)
{
}
```

Is it possible to have a non-public constructor, or is a public one absolutely required?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). _Why_ don't you want a parameterless constructor, which MVC needs by default?

Comment: @TimothyGroote no, that question just mentions the solution for the error the OP gets, namely to add a parameterless contrstructor.

Comment: hiding the parameterless constructor for a POCO with read/write properties is just crap

Comment: @CodeCaster hmm, should have read better. i figured someone cleared up why it needed to be public in that thread. excuse me.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219333/2029468) to a similar question might help you.

Comment: @SirRufo - you've got a point here. Its just a way to show explicitly which properties are required, though.

Comment: @Bartosz Show to ... the controller, the model binder, ... - use data annotations, flag the required properties and then just query if the model is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use any constructor you like, but you will have to do the model binding yourself then. The problem is in `DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel`, which uses a [parameterless public constructor](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs#L398).

You have to override the default model binder and create your own. If that is worth the time is up to you.

Steps to take:

- Override `CreateModel`;
- Check the `modelType` for some generic constraint which models you need to call the constructor with parameters on;
- Call [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) with the parameters. You could obtain their values from the `bindingContext`;
- Register the model binder, either through the `ModelBinder` attribute, or globally.

[Read more on custom bindings here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding)

Comment: _"and create your own"_ - and then what? How would that one instantiate this model? (Yes, I know you can [instantiate an object without calling a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296584/create-object-instance-without-invoking-constructor)).

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Yeah so that's a whole lot of work for simply not having to create a parameterless constructor and applying `[Required]` attributes, what is what the OP appears to actually want.

Comment: If you can change the constructor, yes. If you are stuck with a third-party library, you might not. @CodeCaster

Comment: @Bartosz read _"If that is worth the time is up to you"_ and let it sink in. You're not only costing yourself a lot of time right now for things that have a simpler solution, you're also prone to running into bugs and confusing your later self and future developers of this project.

Comment: @Patrick and that's why you don't use models from outside your own MVC project (apart from a separate viewmodels assembly) as view models. Simply create a simple POCO and map to and from that one. :)

Comment: I saw that one coming @CodeCaster :)

Comment: Consider it a pet peeve of mine! :D I've seen it go wrong more often than not. Yes, I have played with model binders myself, and it's fun to do, but for the average application you really don't want to.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Oh yes, I did consider it and of course I am not going to use that - it makes little sense in this scenario. However, I mainly ask questions to learn whether XXX is possible, not necessarily to implement it. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

Also, while Patrick's answer is great and shows how to do it (in scenarios where this much effort really makes sense), I just add something I've noticed in another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219305/does-asp-net-mvc-allow-private-viewmodel-constructor/12219333#12219333).

Basically, mark the parameterless constructor as `[Obsolete("Comment to indicate its for binding only")]` and that will prevent others from accidentally calling the parameterless one. (Thus showing explicitly which properties are required  by the request object)